# Python hangs with Qt bindings

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a 2.6 python installed with latest PySide Qt bindings. The following code hands if `thread.start()` line is uncommented. Anyone can suggest what i'm doing wrong?

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

app = QApplication( sys.argv )
window = QWidget()
window.show()
thread = QThread()
# thread.start()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because QThread::start tries to use the event loop which isn't running until you do app.exec_(), seems possible, anyway.

Comment: you asked about this in #pyside on IRC and got an answer for, didn't you? Care to put it as an answer and accept it? It may be helpful for others.

Comment: Sure thing. I just give over people some time to answer it. It's not very polite to answer own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'a a known PySide bug. The workaround is to subclass `QThread` and define `run()` method that calls `exec_()`